# Нужен совет по безопастности

Tags: linux, django, nginx, безопасность

Всем доброго дня.

Есть у меня веб сайт для обслуживания кафе (принимает заказы от кассира), вот этот сайт должен работать на планшете, мне нужно так обезопасить чтобы только с этого планшета заходил, 
Но есть ньюансы возможны администраторы (их двоя) будут заходить в админ панель из дома или через телефон, как сделать так что бы левые люди или уволенные сотрудники дома или где то не зашли?

Openssh хорошая идея но админы заходят своем компе или через телефон, говорят сертификатами им не удобно. или есть другая идея?

Сервер на Убунту, nginx, django

p.s У всех есть логин и пароль, (но это не поможет так как другой кассир может из дома зайти)

Comment: Выдать каждому сотруднику логин и пароль, входить только по паролю, после увольнения пароль удалять

Comment: Ну и сертификат тоже можно выдать как вариант. Сертификаты прекрасно работают в браузерах, openssh для этого не нужен

Comment: @andreymal Там изначально есть пароль, но кассиров несколько, и они могут дома зайти по логину и паролю и натворить страшное

Comment: Если у планшета есть конкретный внешний IP-адрес, можно ограничить вход по IP-адресу например

Comment: @andreymal  проблема в том что нет белого ip адреса, и админы тоже заходят в этот ip

Comment: Тогда подключаться к серверу через корпоративный VPN, чтобы этот VPN выдал планшету конкретный IP-адрес и приватную подсеть. Но тогда настройки подключения должны быть спрятаны и недоступны пользователю планшета, чтобы сотрудник не смог прочитать их и подключиться к VPN из дома

Comment: @andreymal Если vpn использовать, то лучше и планшету по vpn подключать? не мучаться подсетями

Comment: А кто у вас админит сеть? Из вопроса мне кажется вы не совсем понимаете, что именно вам блокировать и почему такое низкое доверие. OpenSSH хорош для котрооя самого "планшета" - установка системных пакетов, рестарт деманов - зачем бухгалтеру это ножно делать? И как у вас происходит проброс с плашета в глобальную сет если брендиауэр?

Comment: может попробовать по мак-адресу?

Comment: и по данным, что это планшет и тд.

Comment: @ZaArs, мак виден только в пределах локальной сети и то через спец запросы.

Comment: В чём проблема НЕСКОЛЬКИХ логинов и РАЗНЫМ уровнем доступа и системой логов\бэкапов, чтобы можно было посмотреть кто что натворил и откатиться на рабочее состояние?

Comment: @Hellseher там сис админов нет, и с бэкапами будут проблемы, они заказали программу я создал, просто нужно запретить кассирам заходить дома. есть там хозяин кафе, для него написана дэшбоард он где угодна доджен заходить с телефона и пк

Comment: @donRumata  откатить будет проблема, так как у заказчика нет сис админов, создал програмуу и продал, просто для безопастности, нужно было сделать так что бы принимать заказы только с этого планшета, а хозяин может где угодно заходить

Comment: Ну эту проблему как раз и решают разные учётные записи с разным уровнем доступа. Бэкапы тогда делай средствами самой проги возьми за основу типа git или rdiff-backup.